# Unix: Trying to increment a calender year and display

Tags: bash

I have a unix assignment and What I have isnt working right. It doesnt format like the normal "cal" function.

```
#!/bin/bash

d=`date '+%Y'`;
$((++d));
calstr=`cal $d`;
echo $calstr;
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do instead? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `$` in line 2, and you need to wrap the `$calstr` in double quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash

d=`date '+%Y'`;
((++d));
calstr=`cal $d`;
echo "$calstr";
```